# Comunicação entre arquivos PHP com Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Bom dia, pessoal.

Estou iniciando com o PHP, e estou tentando fazer uns testes práticos.

Criei um input text e quando apertar a tecla "ENTER" é chamado um ajax fazendo post desses dados e chama o arquivo controle.php, porém no log do browser não está mencionando nem a mensagem de "Sucesso" do `.done` e nem "Erro" do `.fail`, muito menos a mensagem do `controle.php`.

Podem me explicar o que está acontecendo nesses scripts?

**tela.php**

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<form>
    <div class="row">
        Campo de Texto: 
        <input id="id_text" style="height: 25px; font-size:12px; width: 100px" type ="text">
    </div>
</form>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var texto = document.getElementById('id_text').value;

$('#id_text').bind("enterKey",function(e){
    console.log("Pressionado ENTER "+ texto);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "controle.php",
        data: {
            'texto': texto
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log("Sucesso");
    }).fail(function(data){
        console.error("Ajax Error");
    });
});
$('#id_text').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
});
});
```

**controle.php**

```
<?php
$reqmethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if($reqmethod == 'POST'){
    $texto  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "texto");
    echo "O texto é: " + $texto;
}else{
    echo "Não é um POST";
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perdão pela demora na resposta.

Caso ainda esteja com problemas, segue código e considerações:

- Em controle.php na concatenação da frase existia um '+' como operador. Essa notação é do javascript, para fazer a união entre dois textos no php se utiliza o operador '.';
- A acentuação deu problema, por esse motivo coloquei um utf8_encode().
- No script.js , trouxe um alert para que mostrasse a frase digitada.

segue telas alteradas para comparação e estudo:

**controle.php**

```
<?php
$reqmethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if($reqmethod == 'POST'){
    $texto  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "texto");
    echo utf8_encode("O texto é: ". $texto);
}else{
    echo "Não é um POST";
}

?>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#id_text').bind("enterKey",function(e){
    var texto = document.getElementById('id_text').value;

    console.log("Pressionado ENTER "+ texto);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "controle.php",
        data: {
            'texto': texto
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log("Sucesso" + data);
        alert(unescape(data));
    }).fail(function(data){
        console.error("Ajax Error");
    });
});
$('#id_text').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }

});

$(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})

});
```

**tela.php**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<form>
    <div class="row">
        Campo de Texto: 
        <input id="id_text" style="height: 25px; font-size:12px; width: 100px" type ="text">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Caro, não é preciso criar duas respostas, apenas edite a primeira.

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela informação, não tinha pensado nisto. Apaguei a mensagem antiga para evitar confusão. Obrigado.